# Delete a table row and Firebase register using JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, firebase, handlebars.js

I am using firebase-database to register reservation data, and showing them on a HTML table with 'child_added' and showing them using Handlebars templates, and there is a delete icon on each row of the table, but I am not able to delete any row.
While I was trying to get the 'id' and match the with the  selected and the one in the Firebase, the id in the Console is 'undefined'.

This is how the database structure looks like:

reservation: {
id:   "-L0hxuTkOKFDyxAyMvF8"
date: "Wed Dec 27 2017 11:00:00 GMT+1100 (AEDT)"
name: "maisa"
time: "5:00PM"
}

JS file

```
$('.reservation-list').on('click', '.delete', function(e) {


    // Get the ID for the comment we want to update
    var id = $(this).closest('tr').data('id');

    // find comment whose objectId is equal to the id we're searching with
    var commentReference = database.ref('reservation/' + id);

    // Use remove method to remove the reservation from the database
    commentReference.remove();

});
```

HTML

```
<script id="reservation-template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">

    <tr>
        <td>{{name}}</td>
        <td>{{date}}</td>
        <td>{{time}}</td>
        <td>
            <i class="fa fa-trash delete"></i>
        </td>
    </tr>   
</script>
```

HTML

[Head of the table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iSvSz.png)

```
<table class="table table-striped container-fluid">
<thead>
<tr>
<th>Name</th>
<th>Day</th>
<th>Time</th>
<tr>
</thead>
<tbody class="reservation-list"></tbody>
</table>
```

Could someone help me to identify why I can not delete an item from the table and Firebase through the ID?
Thanks.

Comment: You are missing the data-id attribute in your example on your tr element. You are also targeting .reservation-template which doesn't exist in your example and probably should be #reservation-template

Comment: "reservation-template" I use to get the data from Firebase and show in HTML. I do not need to use it to delete the data. I am using "reservation-list".                                                                                                         
                     <table class="table table-striped container-fluid">
       <thead>
        <tr>
         <th>Name</th>
         <th>Day</th>
         <th>Time</th>
        <tr>
       </thead>
       <tbody class="reservation-list"></tbody>
      </table>

Comment: that makes sense, but it might be easier for someone to debug if you include the code showing where your data-id exists on your tr element.

Comment: You are still missing <tr data-id="{{id}}"> otherwise your jquery will return undefined.

Comment: In fact, It does not exist. This ID comes from Firebase database. I used data('id') to try to get this ID from Firebase and compare the data I am trying to delete in my table <tr>. Every reservation is linked to an id according to  the second paragraph described in my post.

Comment: I'm a bit confused as this line $(this).closest('tr').data('id'); in Jquery gets you a data attribute from an existing HTML element and has no relation to Firebase, although you may use the returned value to select or delete an id from your database.

Comment: If the problem is that you are not getting a reference returned from the database it maybe because the line database.ref('reservation/' + id); should reference a database structure like reservation:{-L0hxuTkOKFDyxAyMvF8:{name: "maisa"...}} and not the one you've posted.

Comment: I posted the wrong structure. Make sense what you said. Still struggling here to make this delete button works. I will try to write the code again.